# Moiblefirst CLI error 340

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

flowing [this link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/advanced-client-side-development/using-cli-create-build-manage-project-artifacts/) for installation MFP 
CLI

downlaod install successfully.... 
[image]
[image]
then run cmd in my windows pc then try to  run with flowing comment

```
 C:\Program Files\IBM\MobileFirst-CLI>mobilefirst create projectName
```

this error throwing

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\IBM\MobileFirst-CLI\mobilefirst-cli\
    bin\mobilefirst-cli.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
        at startup (node.js:119:16)
        at node.js:929:3
```

what am  i missing. please help me

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem ... when you download CLI Zip from IBM site . first of all you need to `Extract all` not `Run`

[image]